# How to use VectorAngle[] in AnglePath3D[]?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, code-request, geometric-transform

Suppose I have a specific angle that I calculate from two vectors, in 3D:

```
center = {0, 0, 0};
v1 = {1, 0, 0};
v2 = {-1, 0.3, 0.3};
Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, Line[{center, v1}], Blue, Line[{center, v2}]}]
```

[image]

The angle between `v1` and `v2`:

```
myAngle = VectorAngle[v1, v2]
(*2.74035*)
```

Question is, how can I feed `myAngle` into `AnglePath3D[]`? The result should take the last step on `AnglePath3D[]` as the reference orientation to generate the next step, according to `myAngle`. I suspect that this requires the [EulerAngles[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerAngles.html) calculated at each sequential step, but unsure how to find them to feed into `AnglePath3D[]` (I'm guessing getting the rotation matrix from each sequential Euler angles(?)).

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: If, per @chris suggestion, one does `path=AnglePath3D[N@ConstantArray[{0, myAngle}, 5], {"Position","RotationTranslation"}]`:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Line[path[[All, 1]]],
  GeometricTransformation[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {0.1, 0.05, 0.05}], 
   path[[All, 2]]]
  },
 ImageSize -> 350,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}
 ]
```

[image]

This seems to work, but the path has no "depth", as it is contained on a single plane on the Y axis. I'm just guessing there's not enough information in `{0, myAngle}` to reorient the new step in the same 3D way `v2` is reoriented relative to `v2` (see below):

[image]

If you could explain how to properly specify the last vector as the new 'frame of reference', that would be great. I imagine this requires reorienting this angles on the three axes (X, Y, Z), so that the new step is on the same relative orientation to the last step, as `v2` is from `v1` in this simple example. Any help/explanation/clarifications would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the end of the documentation? It seems to me the last (neat example) gives you the answer? `path = AnglePath3D[
   N@ConstantArray[{0, -\[Pi]/100}, 200], {"Position", 
    "RotationTranslation"}];`

Comment: @chris doing `AnglePath3D[N@ConstantArray[{0, myAngle},20], {"Position", "RotationTranslation"}];` seems to work. But, why do I need the zero in `{0, myAngle}`. And, do you know what the relation of this solution to the Euler Angles? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't understand what you're trying to do.  I think saying your purpose clearly can help people understand the problem.

Have you ever tried using

```
RotationMatrix[{v1, v2}]
```

to get the rotation matrix. And this can directly used as the input of `AnglePath3D`.

After some discussion we got

```
path = AnglePath3D[N@ConstantArray[EulerAngles[RotationMatrix[{v1,v2}]], 5], {"Position", "RotationTranslation"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried to explain better in my edited question. Using `RotationMatrix[]` requires the coordinates of `v1`/`v2`. I'm trying to use the angles calculated with `VectorAngle[]`, as stated in the question.

Comment: But with only one angle, you can't do a certain rotation.

Comment: right! I think I deleted the part about `EulerAngles[]` (now I re-added that), but you're right. One single angle doesn't tell which general orientation in 3D one should get. So, I think you are close to an answer. I'm guessing finding at each new step the rotation matrix, then calculating the `EulerAngles[]` iteratively would be a solution? If you post this answer, I think that's it, thanks!

Comment: So the Euler Angle for each rotation is known?

Comment: Well, I think I can calculate it with `EulerAngles[]`. In fact, I tried `path = AnglePath3D[N@ConstantArray[EulerAngles[RotationMatrix[{v1, v2}]], 5], {"Position", "RotationTranslation"}]`, and this seems to work. But, I'm thinking how can I do this without relying on `v1`, `v2` (because in my more complicated application, the angles I need vary, so I can't just use `v1`/`v2` as a constant). However, I think this gives a good path towards what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But in fact you have to have three parameters to determine a rotation. Even if you don't use specific coordinates, you have to give euler angles or something equivalent. I think I need to know what quantities you know.

Comment: That's right. So, in fact, the three parameters in the Euler angles is what is needed, and I didn't know how to find them until now. By our discussion I've found the answer to my application. If you modify your answer to be `path = AnglePath3D[N@ConstantArray[EulerAngles[RotationMatrix[{v1,v2}]], 5], {"Position", "RotationTranslation"}]` I'll take it as valid. So, thanks for your questions! :)